# How do I add UI Children to an empty WPF-Page?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, wpf-controls

I'm having a MainWindow which is a NavigationWindow. Inside this MainWindow I want to switch in several Pages. One of the Pages has to be dynamically generated by Code, not by XAML. When I had a normal window before, I could add UI components like this:

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Content = "Hello";
this.AddChild(b);
```

Or if I added (for example) a StackPanel with this method first, I could add Children to this StackPanel with:

```
myPanel.Children.Add(b);
```

However, **the Page Class doesn't have a Children Attribute or a AddChild Method.**
The only method I found so far is:

```
AddVisualChild(b);
```

The page shows but I don't see any components which I added with this method.
So how do I add Children to a WPF-Page correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the `Window.AddChild` will throw an exception when you add more than one object to it, because `Window` is a `ContentControl`. `Page` allowes only 1 child .So you set the child using the `Page.Content` property. So you want to add a container to your `Page` and then add children to the container.
For example:

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Content = "Hello";
StackPanel myPanel = new StackPanel();
myPanel.Children.Add(b);
this.Content = myPanel;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't expect the Content Property to be responsible for that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure if this works for you but you could try to set the content of a page to a user control. E.g. use a `StackPanel` and add all the children to it. After that you set the content of the `Page` to the `Stackpanel`.

Here is an lazy example in the constructor of a MainWindow.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();
    Button b1 = new Button {Content = "Hello"};
    Button b2 = new Button {Content = "Hi"};

    panel.Children.Add(b1);
    panel.Children.Add(b2);

    Page page = new Page {Content = panel};

    this.Content = page;
}
```

Comment: Ok I wasn't fast enought :).